# issue with asp:hyperlink and NavigateUrl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

I am having an issue with using the NavigateUrl within a HyperLink asp.net tag.
The navigationUrl works as in go to the page I want it to go, but when I try to get the Query String "n" it gives me <% instead of the number value within the DataBind. Here is the code:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/MyWebsite/info.aspx?n='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Conatainer.DataItem, "num")%>' />
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/MyWebsite/info.aspx?n={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.num").ToString())%>' >Text</asp:HyperLink>
```